# How can I echo a javascript variable into a special field in a stripe html script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, echo

I'm really block on this :
I want to print the content of a javascript variable into the "data-amount" and the "data-description" field of my script (i'm using the script for the stripe payement API) in the html, and I really don't know how to do this...

Here's the javascript that will echo the value :

```
 $(".totalPricesNoEngagementStripe2").text(parseInt(initialPrice) + parseInt(total));
```

Here's the script (from stripe API) :

```
<form action="setCharge.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="simple_engagement">
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
                data-description="PRINT JS VARIABLE HERE"
                data-amount="PRINT JS VARIABLE HERE"
                data-locale="auto"
                data-currency="eur"></script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with vanilla JS:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('stripe-button')[0];

el.setAttribute('data-description', 'Here is the description');
el.setAttribute('data-amount', 'Here is the amount');

console.log(el)
```

```html
<form action="setCharge.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="simple_engagement">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="<?php //echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>" data-description="PRINT JS VARIABLE HERE" data-amount="PRINT JS VARIABLE HERE" data-locale="auto" data-currency="eur"></script>
</form>
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute